# Unexpected regular expression behavior using Positive Lookbehind

Tags: java, regex

I was writing a regular expression to match a sequence of digits, followed by a dot and then another sequence of digits, and in total length, including the dot, the entire sequence should be 13. For this purpose, the regular expression that I wrote was: `(\d{6,12})\.(\d{0,6})(?<=.{13})`

When I run this expression against the two following samples of data, I was expecting only the second one to match, but instead, both are mathed. Can anyone help me understand why?

- `1234567.123456` > is matched but I was expecting it not to be matched;
- `1234567.12345` > is matched.

Here is the Java code I used to test this:
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d{6,12})\\.(\\d{0,6})(?<=.{13})");
        System.out.println(matcher.matcher("1234567.123456").matches());
        System.out.println(matcher.matcher("1234567.12345").matches());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to anchor the lookbehind assertion to the start of the string, or it will match a substring:

```
Pattern matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d{6,12})\\.(\\d{0,6})(?<=^.{13})");
```

Or use a lookahead assertion instead (easier to understand, IMO):

```
Pattern matcher = Pattern.compile("(?=.{13}$)(\\d{6,12})\\.(\\d{0,6})");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use anchor to match at the beginning of the string:

```
"(\\d{6,12})\\.(\\d{0,6})(?<=^.{13})"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add an anchor (`^`) to your lookbehind expression:

```
(?<=^.{13})
```